# How to properly unit test RestEasy responses?

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, mockito, resteasy

I have a RESTEasy client endpoint which connects to a REST-based database server which gives JSON responses.
The data model of the other end (POJOs annotated with JSON annotations) are available for use.

I would like to properly unit test the methods that are communicating with requests/responses. Test code written with the help of JUnit and Mockito.

The picture gets more complicated in case of a method that sends a request, needs to parse the JSON result, should extract the new ID of the created entity and "reuse" this ID to make another request to replace the automatically generated device name into a more readable and friendlier name. I was thinking of maybe this method should be broken apart to two methods, but I can't see any clean and good solution because this method will be used as an access point from other components in the system, therefore one method should accomplish one thing.

Enough of talking, let's see the code itself:

```
public void createDevice(final Device device) {
    final RequestDescriptor requestDescriptor = new DeviceCreateRequestDescriptor(device);
    final RequestCreator requestCreator = new RequestCreator(requestDescriptor, HttpMethod.POST, uriBuilder);
    final ClientRequest request = requestCreator.create();
    final ClientResponse response = executor.execute(request);
    final String responseString = (String) response.getEntity(String.class);

    //JSON unmarshall logic will be here
    //I should get the device ID from the response, doable with e.g. Jackson
    String deviceId = "";

    changeDeviceName(device, deviceId);
}

   private void changeDeviceName(final Device device, final String deviceId) throws Exception {
    final UriBuilderWrapper uriBuilder = new UriBuilderWrapper(databaseConfig,
            m2mInterfaceContainer.getM2MProvisioningInterface());
    final RequestDescriptor requestDescriptor = new DeviceNameChangeRequestDescriptor(device, deviceId);
    final RequestCreator requestCreator = new RequestCreator(requestDescriptor, HttpMethod.POST, uriBuilder);
    final ClientRequest request = requestCreator.create();
    executor.execute(request);
}
```

My test code looks like :

```
@Test
public void testCreateDeviceSendsTwoRequests() throws Exception {
    clientExecutorWrapper = mock(ClientExecutorWrapper.class);

    m2mDeviceManager = new M2MDeviceManager();
    device = new Device("123456666", "6789066666");
    m2mDeviceManager.createDevice(device);

    final ArgumentCaptor<ClientRequest> requestCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ClientRequest.class);
    verify(clientExecutorWrapper, times(2)).execute(requestCaptor.capture());

    final List<ClientRequest> capturedRequests = requestCaptor.getAllValues();

    final Map<String, String> expectedFormParametersForCreateDeviceRequest = createExpectedFormParametersForFirstRequest();
    final Map<String, String> expectedFormParametersForChangeNameRequest = createExpectedFormParametersForSecondRequest();

    final String expectedUrlCreateDeviceRequest = "dummy_url_1;
    final String expectedUrlForChangeNameRequest = "dummy_url_2";
    RequestChecker.checkRequest(capturedRequests.get(0), expectedFormParametersForCreateDeviceRequest,
            expectedUrlCreateDeviceRequest);
    RequestChecker.checkRequest(capturedRequests.get(1), expectedFormParametersForChangeNameRequest,
            expectedUrlForChangeNameRequest);
}
```

My helper methods for the test case looks like:

```
private Map<String, String> createExpectedFormParametersForFirstRequest() {
    final Map<String, String> expectedFormParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    expectedFormParameters.put("some_param","some_value");
    // ... other form parameters
    return expectedFormParameters;
}

private Map<String, String> createExpectedFormParametersForSecondRequest() {
    final Map<String, String> expectedFormParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    expectedFormParameters.put("some_param2","some_value2");
    // ... other form parameters
    return expectedFormParameters;
}
```

The `RequestChecker` helper class for the test looks like:

```
class RequestChecker {

public static void checkRequest(final ClientRequest request, final Map<String, String> expectedFormParameters,
        final String expectedUrl) throws Exception {
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters = request.getFormParameters();
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = request.getQueryParameters();

    assertEquals(expectedUrl, request.getUri());

    assertTrue(queryParameters.size() == 0);
    checkFormParameters(expectedFormParameters, formParameters);

 }

private static void checkFormParameters(final Map<String, String> expectedFormParameters,
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters) {
    final Set<Entry<String, String>> expectedParameters = expectedFormParameters.entrySet();
    for (final Entry<String, String> expectedParameter : expectedParameters) {
        final String expectedParameterName = expectedParameter.getKey();
        final String expectedParameterValue = expectedParameter.getValue();
        final List<String> actualFormParameters = formParameters.get(expectedParameterName);
        checkFormParameter(actualFormParameters, expectedParameterValue);
    }
}

 private static void checkFormParameter(final List<String> actualFormParameters, final String expected) {
    assertNotNull(actualFormParameters);
    assertTrue(actualFormParameters.size() == 1);
    assertEquals(expected, actualFormParameters.get(0));
 }
}
```

So basically I would like to build up my unit test for this something like:

Mock the `executor` (somehow) to correctly generate JSON results based on the requests.
Correct me if I'm wrong but I could marshal back the JSON result if I build up the mocked object hierarchy.
My problem here is that I need to create the hierarchy for every single request, but I guess I cannot do anything fancier here.
I should assert that the `changeDeviceName` method invoked with the expected device ID.

Questions:

1. Is it okay to test the unmarshal logic independently from this to ensure all other methods do the unmarshalling as expected or are there any better way of doing this?
2. Are there any applicable refactor patterns I can use to make this a bit cleaner? These two methods are too tighly coupled.
3. Are there any cleaner approach instead of this testcase. I hope I can get something better, I don't like these argument captors and generally too much code is needed to simply describe this case and there will be many types of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is much subjective and my answer will be also IMO:

1. I would go such way as well. as for me I saw a lot of times when bug/issue is caught on the implementation level or after server/client REST API migration
2. There are some duplication - `RequestDescriptor, RequestCreator, ClientRequest, ClientResponse`. So you could extract some classes to reduce this boilerplate code. Take look to Square `Retrofit` example https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-samples/github-client/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/GitHubClient.java
3. Someone could say, that integration tests are more valuable and could be used not as addition but instead of unit tests for REST. But I don't think so. And yes, we are exposing a lot details of the implementation here, it means every change you have to change tests as well

I would probably also convert requests to url and bodies. And use string or JSON comparison for asserts. That would be much less code

Answer (score 0):

For integration tests and to test the resteasy service deployed in a server [restassured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) is the good one.